# This is a question about graphing calculators, the TI-84 Plus, etc ones. How do I connect them to my laptop?

Tags: calculator

All of the videos and information I can find about connecting TI-84 Plus/etc calculators to laptops are outdated. And the only type of cord I can find is [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07RKTNR38) with the end that's too large for my MacBook Air port, which is the small smooth port.
Does anyone know if there is a cord you can use to connect the TI-84 to newer apple laptops?
I just want to be able to import programs from my laptop to solve math problems into my calculator instead of writing them.

Comment: 1. This isn't technically about math as defined [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).  And 2, my guess is your laptop has USB-C ports and the cable you've linked uses USB-A, so you would just need a USB-A to USB-C adapter which I know Apple sells but the brand doesn't really matter.

Comment: Okay thank you and sorry. Next time I'll ask a question like this elsewhere.